# Should removing "Community Wiki" from a question also remove "Community Wiki" from all the answers?

Tags: discussion

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/why-is-infinity-minus-infinity-a-community-wiki-question discussed whether it was appropriate for [What is the result of infinity minus infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/what-is-the-result-of-infinity-minus-infinity) to have been made a Community Wiki, and the consensus was that it shouldn't have been.

A moderator then removed the Community Wiki flag from the question. However, all the answers are still Community Wiki...

Should the answers all have the Community Wiki flag removed too? Does that have any impact other than granting Rep to the answerers? And is that good enough reason to do it?

Comment: I removed the CW status from the question, and I thought that would have automatically undone it for the answers too (since they became CW by virtue of the question having been made CW), but apparently not. I'll remove the CW status from the answers too, although if there are good reasons against it posted here we can always add it back.

Comment: Perfect for this question, thanks. I guess, though, the generalised question still stands? Is there any reason *not* to do it? Could/should it be made automatic?

Comment: @Bill: I'd rather not make it automatic. Sometimes people deliberately post CW answers for a reason. Undoing this "automatically" would be doing a disfavour. Since situations like this doesn't come up very often, I'd rather leave more work for the mods instead of opening up possible programming bugs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mechanically speaking, it doesn't, and Willie Wong explains why in a comment. Sometimes, people personally mark it, and the reversal of the status does not examine for this. As such it only affects just the root post.

In the scenario where you're trying to undo a community wiki status which itself forced all of the answers to also be community wiki, it's certainly possible to look into removing the status from all the answers. I would recommend it be done manually when this kind of scenario turns up.

Comment: It seems to me this answer suggests a further question: would it be desirable for the software to track _why_ a post was made CW (and if so, how feasible would it be)?

Comment: @Ilmari Excepting moderator conversion (which, well, is just marked as such), there should actually have been a change pushed in which automatic community wiki is explained as to what triggered it in the revision history.